# Attempting to Create a Simple "Debugger" (A Trivial C Program)

Tags: c, arrays, string, indices

I attempted to create a simple C program which notifies the user when braces are "unbalanced". However, the results are often incorrect. For instance, the input {{}}, prompts the error statement rather than "no errors detected." Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Note: I am a beginner! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        char filter[100]; // "Filtered" array (contains braces)
        char s[100]; 

        int i; // Increment variables
        int j;
        int z;
        int l;
        int c;

        int linecount = 0;
        int pair = 0; // Brace pair {}
        int k = 0;
        int y = 1;


        while (y == 1)
        {

                linecount++;

                for (i = 0; i < 99 &&  (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; i++) 
                        s[i] = c; // Initializing array with a line

                if (c == EOF)
                        break;


                for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                        if (s[j] == '{'|| s[j] == '}') // Filter extraneous characters
                                s[j] = filter[k++];
                }

                if (filter[0] == '{') // Determines if filtered array starts with {
                {

                        for (z = 0, l = (k-1);  z < k && l >= 0; z++, l--) //Determine pairs
                        {
                                if (filter[z] == '{' && filter[l] == '}')
                                        pair++;
                        }

                        if (pair > 0)
                                printf("No errors detected.\n");
                }

                else
                        printf("Line %d: syntactic error.\n", linecount);
        }
}
~
```

Comment: Parsing (or even just lexing) C correctly is really *quite* challenging. You may well *improve* what you have, but doing this job entirely correctly is a *lot* of work.

Comment: Your read loop stores in `s` starting at 0, but the filter loop starts at 1 and so misses `s[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, Fred! I changed j = 0, but the results are still incorrect. In addition, assigning l = (k-1) is correct, right? Since k will increment by one in the "filter loop" when j = i.

Comment: You really should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)... Using the debugger is an essential skill.

Comment: And your program is *not* a "debugger", it is a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser).

Comment: Thanks, Basille. I used the term debugger in a trivial sense, hence the quotations.

Answer (score 2):

A better and neater way to implement the "unbalanced" checking is by using a stack.
The overall algorithm can be simplified as.

1. if you encounter a `{` push it onto the stack.
2. if you encounter a '}' check if the stack is empty, 
     if not, pop the `}` from the stack, ie for each `}` there should be one `{`
     if the stack is empty, there is some unbalanced `}`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write such a complicated program. Just use a counter to count the bracket *level*. Like so ...

```
/* At the beginning of the file/funciton */
curlyCounter = 0;

/* read characters one at a time in a variable called c */

if (c == '{') curlyCounter++;
if (c == '}') curlyCounter--;

/* at the end of the program or ufnction */

if (c == 0){
    /* Correctly formed expression */
} else {
    /* Incorrectly formed expression*/
}
```

This is much simpler and should solve your problem. Note that if you want to solve other brackets as well, you will need to have a more involved solver. You will need recursive stack implementations.

Comment: Thanks! A concise and logical solution :)

Comment: What about "} {" ? The end result is still zero. The stack-based solution of nu11p01n73R seems like the way to go to me.

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed first is that `s[j]` is on the left side in: `s[j] = filter[k++]`. so it is `s[]` that gets filled up with the empty elements of `filter[]`

Second, since `for(z, l)` iterates from the start of `filter[]` till the end with the two variables, and their values are symmetric, you double-check every element of `filter[]`.

Third, since the values of `z` and `l` *are* symmetric, this condition only works if the arrangement of braces is like this: `{{{}}}`, or `{{}}` or `{}`, and not in `{{}}}` or `{}}}`. because pair is incremented in the last case even when `filter[1] = '}'` and `filter[k-2] = '}'`

Also, when you get to `filter[2] = '}'`  (the right one in the middle) and `filter[k-3] = '}'` (the left one in the middle).

Edit: By the way, i said it wrong that `s[]` gets filled up with "empty" elements, under which i meant undefined: because `filter[]` is a static array, its elements are all set to 0 if not explicitly initialized, as according to C99 standard behaviour at least.